# python remove http hyperlink

Tags: python, http, loops, for-loop

I would like to remove hyperlinks from my tweets
For instance:
I have: "Reform health care to serve patients, not corporate medicine 
    http://t.co/WMKJKU4hl7 @PNHP #SinglePayerSunday http://t.co/i4bNrruUNS"
But I want to get:"Reform health care to serve patients, not corporate medicine"
How could it be possible?
Thanks ahead!

Upon the suggestions, I rewrite the code for my whole list of tweets. I wrote a for loop, but did not work:

I tried this one, because I have a list of tweets., but did not work for the

`for i in range(len(cleandata)):
    finaldata=[]
    if 'http://' in cleandata[i]:
        post = cleandata[i]
        position = post.index('http://')
        finaldata.append(post[:position])
    else:
        finaldata.append(cleandata[i])`
cleandata is my tweet list
Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Do you want to remove everything after the first occurrence of `http://`?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the position where `http://` is , and then slice it.

```
post = "Reform health care to serve patients, not corporate medicine http://t.co/WMKJKU4hl7 @PNHP #SinglePayerSunday http://t.co/i4bNrruUNS"
position = post.index('http://')
print post[:position]
```

result

```
Reform health care to serve patients, not corporate medicine
```

Comment: Actually now I have another problem, I was trying to put it in a for loop, because indeed I have a list of tweets.

Comment: I tried to put it into a for loop, but did not work. I posted my current code above.. I am sorry that I couldn't make it work

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `re`

```
import re
post = "Reform health care to serve patients, not corporate medicine http://t.co/WMKJKU4hl7 @PNHP #SinglePayerSunday http://t.co/i4bNrruUNS"
print re.sub(r'http://.*','',post)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, very small mistake... I corrected it... Thanks guys!

```
'finaldata=[]
for i in range(len(cleandata)):
    if 'http://' in cleandata[i]:
        post = cleandata[i]
        position = post.index('http://')
        finaldata.append(post[:position])
    else:
        finaldata.append(cleandata[i])
```